# Why is a position absolute being computed into a static position

Tags: html, css, styles, css-position

I have an HTML element that has a specific rule for `position: absolute`.
However, it seems that that rule is being computed into a `position: static`.
I don't have any rule that applies the static position, so I would like to know why is it being applied in the computed rules and if there's a way of enforcing the absolute position.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check the outer nodes with position relative? absolute elements "attach" to the first outer element with "position: relative". It may be that, not sure

Comment: the styles you are showing to us are labeled *inherited from* and as you can see position is greyed because is not inherited so if no position was set into the element then the default one (static) will apply